# Publish Master Page

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage

I created a new subsite under my SharePoint 2013 Site. I want to publish master page for the new subsite. I do the following. But my new subsite open default master page. How can I publish from another way?

- Design Manager
- Publish and Apply Design
  [image]
- Master Page Gallery (Publish a Major Version)
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Sharepoint Designer to do this. Go to 'Master Pages', right click on your master page and click on 'Set as default Master Page'.

[image: Sharepoint Designer]

Comment: My custom masterpage oslo.master, default masterpage already.

Comment: @zengel is this on the subsite or parent site? you can check the subsite in Sharepoint designer to open the subsite directly: http://yousharepoint/yoursubsite

Comment: OK but my custom masterpage on the parent site. There is default master page on the subsite. I should publish my custom master page to all subsite.  Does this solution is sufficient? @ citizen

Comment: @zengel it should work if you use "set as default master page" on the subsite.